# Splitting complicated string with regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have very basic knowledge of regular expressions and this one is just too hard for me. I need to split string into three parts.

My input looks like this `XXX YYY:ZZZ:` (always ends with `:ZZZ:`)

- XXX can be anything including `$&+,:;=?@#|'<>.-^*()%!` and spaces
- YYY are alphabetical chars which can end with `.` or are not there at all
- ZZZ is number which can have leading zeroes and is in between two `:` at the end of string

Trickiest string I can come up with is `Lo-rem ip sum.,::0001678154:`. `ZZZ` would be `0001678154` we can get rid off `:ZZZ:` so remaining part is `Lo-rem ip sum.,:` but last char is not either alphanumeric or `.` so that means YYY is not included in this string `XXX` is whatever remained (`Lo-rem ip sum.,:`)

Now I have horrible half functioning code with hardcoded lengths, ifs, substrings and splits I believe you could come up with better solution. Thanks

Comment: What's your expected output for `Lo-rem ip sum.,::0001678154:`? Why don't you try matching instead of splitting?

Comment: you mean this http://regex101.com/r/eP7cH7/2 ?

Comment: Thats exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot you saved me

Comment: Truth is your definition doesn't match the answer. And you have a conflict with XXX and YYY definitions.

Comment: @sln may i know how?

Comment: Sure, `YYY are alphabetical chars`, `ZZZ is number`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below regex would capture and store the three set of characters into three separate groups,

```
^(?<xxx>.*?)(?<yyy>(?:[A-Za-z0-9])+\.?)?:(?<zzz>\d+):$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eP7cH7/4)

`?` after the second group will make the group as optional.